# Is it possible to run windows container with GUI support (like xorg with linux container)?

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v, rendering

i recently started to move our *c++* render tests inside docker containers. I managed to run tests with a Linux based container with *xorg* and *nvidia-toolkit* in Linux just fine. But I'm struggling to find a similar solution for windows based image (windows:2004). Currently I run in a "process" isolation mode which allows me to pass gpu, but the tests require a surface to render, so without a monitor they fail.

My Environment:

**Docker Desktop v4.11.0**

**Docker Engine v20.10.17**

**Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2 19044.1826**

**DirectX WDDM WDDM 2.7**

I'm using windows official image **mcr.microsoft.com/windows:2004**

So my question is can I run similar setup as I do for Linux with docker, but for windows?

Answer (score 2):

MS response to this request is that GUI images are larger, and they simply are working on actively reducing the size. I would suggest testing with Windows Sandbox, you can automate a few things with the `LogonCommand`, share GPU, Video/Audio and folders. Use `.wsb` configuration files for setting up environments. But the sandbox is volatile, so it's better if your task can be executed from a portable directory.

Resources:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview